# Flipping a shape made by user input

Tags: python

So currently I have to create a shape made out of asterisks based on user input.

This is my code currently that will create the shapes

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(1,num+1):
     for j in range(1,i+1):
         print("*",end="")
     print()
```

with the output of:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

and

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(num,0,-1):
    print("*"*i)
```

output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I need to flip them to look like:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

and

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

I am struggling to find a solution, though I'm sure it must be quite simple to flip them.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: An obvious method would be `print(" "*(num-i),"*"*i)`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`rjust` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) to right-justify your strings: `("*" * i).rjust(num)`

Answer (score 0):

you can just `print` the spaces

```
num = 5
for i in range(1, num+1):
    print(' ' * (num - i) + '*' * i)
```

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```